# False sharing in multi threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

The following code runs slower as I increase the **NTHREADS**. Why use more threads make the program run slower? Is there any way to fix it? Someone said it is about *false sharing* but I do not really understand that concept.

The program basicly calculate the sum from 1 to 100000000. The idea to use multithread is to seperate the number list into several chuncks, and calculate the sum of each chunck parallelly to make the calculation faster.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LENGTH 100000000
#define NTHREADS 2
#define NREPEATS 10
#define CHUNCK (LENGTH / NTHREADS)

typedef struct {
        size_t id;
        long *array;
        long result;
} worker_args;

void *worker(void *args) {

        worker_args *wargs = (worker_args*) args;

        const size_t start = wargs->id * CHUNCK;
        const size_t end = wargs->id == NTHREADS - 1 ? LENGTH : (wargs->id+1) * CHUNCK;

        for (size_t i = start; i < end; ++i) {
                wargs->result += wargs->array[i];
        }

        return NULL;
}

int main(void) {

        long* numbers = malloc(sizeof(long) * LENGTH);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < LENGTH; ++i) {
                numbers[i] = i + 1;
        }

        worker_args *args = malloc(sizeof(worker_args) * NTHREADS);

            for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
                    args[i] = (worker_args) {
                            .id = i,
                            .array = numbers, 
                            .result = 0
                    };
            }

            pthread_t thread_ids[NTHREADS];

            for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
                    pthread_create(thread_ids+i, NULL, worker, args+i);
            }

            for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
                    pthread_join(thread_ids[i], NULL);
            }

            long sum = 0;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < NTHREADS; ++i) {
                sum += args[i].result;
            }

            printf("Run %2zu: total sum is %ld\n", n, sum);

        free(args);
        free(numbers);
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `100000000*100000001/2` ;-)

Comment: This just aim to practice using multi-thread. @4386427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why use more threads make the program run slower?

There is an overhead creating and joining threads. If the threads hasn't much to do then this overhead may be more expensive than the actual work.

Your threads are only doing a simple sum which isn't that expensive. Also consider that going from e.g. 10 to 11 threads doesn't change the work load per thread a lot.

10 threads --> 10000000 sums per thread

11 threads -->  9090909 sums per thread

The overhead of creating an extra thread may exceed the "work load saved" per thread.

On my PC the program runs in less than 100 milliseconds. Multi-threading isn't worth the trouble.

You need a more processing intensive task before multi-threading is worth doing.

Also notice that it seldom make sense to create more threads than the number of cores (incl hyper thread) your computer has.

> false sharing

yes, "false sharing" can impact the performance of a multi-threaded program but I doubt it's the real problem in your case.

"false sharing" is something that happens in (some) cache systems when two threads (or rather two cores) writes to two different variables that belongs to the same cache line. In such cases the two threads/cores competes to own the cache line (for writing) and consequently, they'll have to refresh the memory and the cache again and again. That's bad for performance.

As I said - I doubt that is your problem. A clever compiler will do your loop solely be using CPU registers and only write to memory at the end. You can check the disassemble of your code to see if that is the case.

You can avoid "false sharing" by increasing the sizeof of your struct so that each struct fits the size of a cache line on your system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! But is it possible to be problems with false sharing? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing

Comment: A compiler would need to do a very sophisticated interprocedural analysis and optimization to recognize that the thread function can avoid reading addends from memory.  That's very unlikely to be happening.  However, I agree that there is unlikely to be a false sharing issue, and especially not with the addends, because they are written only by the main thread, before it starts any of the others.  Reads do not invalidate caches.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Re the compiler optimization: As reads isn't a problem for false sharing I didn't refer to reading `wargs->array[i]`. I refer to the writing of `wargs->result` inside the loop. I compile can do all the adds in the loop without any memory write (i.e. keep the running result in a register) and thereby avoid false sharing.